# Alterando valores de uma tabela linha por linha

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2

estou com um pequeno problema.
Possuo uma tabela com valores de estoque, e preciso alterar estes valores da seguinte forma.
O cliente vai inserir uma quantidade que ele deseja fabricar de um certo produto, e no sistema precisa informar a quantidade que vai ser utilizada de cada matéria prima.
Mas qual o meu problema? o JS criado esta retornando o valor da primeira linha *(vezes) a quantidade informada, para cada todas as linhas, quando deveria ser o valor de cada linha *(vezes) a quantidade informada.
Segue o script caso alguem tenha uma LUZ =D

```
    $('#calcular').click(function(){


    var qtd = $('#qtd').val();

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){
            waitingDialog.show('Calculando',{dialogSize: 'sm'});
        },
        success: function(){
            waitingDialog.hide();
            $('.comp_qtd').html(parseInt($('.comp_qtd').html())*parseInt(qtd));
        }
    })

});
```

Segue o botao criado para "Calcular":

```
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <?= $this->Form->input('qtd',[
                                                'label' => 'Quantidade',
                                                'type' => 'text',
                                                'placeholder' => 'Digite a qtd',
                                                'id' => 'qtd',
                                                'name' => 'qtd',
                                                'class' => 'form-control',
                                                'title' => 'Digite a quantidade a ser produzido na OS',
                                                'required' => true
                                            ]);
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <button id="calcular" class="btn btn-primary pula" type="button">Calcular <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></button>
                                        </div>
```

e a tabela que deve ser alterada:

```
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Codigo</th>
                                            <th>Produto</th>
                                            <th>Unidade</th>
                                            <th>Quantidade Necessaria</th>
                                            <th>Quantidade em Estoque</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php foreach($arrayComposicao as $composicao) :?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="comp_codigo"><?= $composicao['Produto']['pro_codigo_id']?></td>
                                            <td id="comp_descricao"><?= $composicao['Produto']['pro_descricao']?></td>
                                            <td id="comp_medida"><?= $composicao['Composicao']['comp_mp_medida']?></td>
                                            <td class="comp_qtd"><?= $composicao['Composicao']['comp_mp_qtd']?></td>
                                            <td id="comp_estoque"><?= $composicao['Produto']['pro_qtd_estoque']?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta criar um id(dinâmico ou id do item) para cada row, 
e fazer o cálculo baseado no id da row.
Por exemplo, pseudo-código:

```
...
(parseInt($('idItem'))*parseInt(qtd)
...
```

Não é uma luz, mas espero que seja uma fagulha ehehhe

Comment: Entendi a ideia, mas como faria para cada <td> buscar um id dinâmico por row?

Comment: Conssegui gerar a ID dinâmica, agora vou pesquisar em como fazer o JS pegar essa id gerada e fazer a alteração de acordo com a id gerada

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma

JS:

```
    $('#calcular').click(function(){


    var qtd = $('#qtd').val();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var id = '#Item' + i;
    }

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){
            waitingDialog.show('Calculando',{dialogSize: 'sm'});
        },
        success: function(){
            waitingDialog.hide();
            for (i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                var id = '#Item' + i;
                $(id).html(parseInt($(id).attr( "value" ))*parseInt(qtd));
            }
        }
    })

});
```

e no HTML a  que deve ser alterada

```
<td class="comp_qtd" id="Item<?=$composicao['Composicao']['comp_mp_item']?>" value="<?php echo $composicao['Composicao']['comp_mp_qtd'];?>"><?php echo $composicao['Composicao']['comp_mp_qtd'];?></td>
```